How did the engines on the ME-262 work?
I have been looking into the ME-262 jet engines recently but cannot quite understand how they worked and was wondering if anyone could explain it to me in a simplified way.

It had a "standard" turbojet: do you want to know how a turbojet works? Or something else?

Please edit your question to specify what it is about the Me-262 engines you don't understand, beyond what is explained in the answers to this question. Otherwise, this question may be closed for not being clear as to what is being asked.

The Me-262 engine sucked air into the front of the engine with a series of rotating fans, compressing it. Fuel was then sprayed into the flow of compressed air and ignited, causing the fuel to burn and the surrounding air inside the engine to heat up and expand. Those expanding gases had to accelerate on their way out the exhaust duct and another fan inside that duct captured some of the kinetic energy in the exhaust flow and used it to spin the compressor fans. The leftover momentum in the departing exhaust downstream of the exhaust fan was greater than the momentum of the air entering the engine and the difference in momentum of a parcel of air passing through the engine per unit time has units of force, which is the thrust of the engine.
